# Scrollbars appearing in overflow container on one machine but not the other

Tags: html, css

A couple of weeks ago, I looked at a web app I created on a different machine (Chrome on Ubuntu) for the first time, and looked in horror at the scrollbars that were appearing in all of my overflow containers. I made a mental note to fix it later, but since I couldn't see the issue when looking at the site on my usual machine, I quickly forgot. I was just looking at it on another machine that I use on occasion (Chrome on Mac), and the scrollbar chaos has returned. However, when viewing my web app on the machine I'm on right now, the scroll bars are behaving as expected. Below are images to demonstrate.

The first is a screenshot from my current machine, of a chat box with `overflow: scroll`:

[image]

Same chat box, same code, same browser, but on my other Mac:

[image]

Look at those ugly things. It's like my browser went back in time 10 years. Both machines have the same version of Chrome (58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)) but differing versions of Apple OS (working one is Sierra 10.12.4, the non-working one is El Capitan 10.11.5). Again, this scrollbar behavior was seen on an Ubuntu machine too. Note that scrollbars work as expected in Firefox on both machines.

EDIT

To demonstrate what is expected, here is an image of the vertical scrollbar that appears only *when scrolling* on the working machine:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try using `overflow:auto;` instead of `overflow:scroll;`. It will fix the issue as it'll show or hide the scrollbar automatically based on content inside the parent!

Comment: I have used `overflow:auto` and it simply hides the scrollbars until the container overflows. Once the container overflows, the unusual scrollbars still appear.

Comment: Which one is unusual to you? Horizontal or vertical one?

Comment: Both are unusual. They aren't supposed to look like that, and should only appear when scrolling. Correct me if I'm wrong, but is this not modern browser behavior? I updated my post with a picture to demonstrate what is expected.

Comment: Actually the scroll bar look varies on different OS. So, same browser with same version can show a scroll bar looks differently like what you're seeing on your machines.
You can't actually change the scroll bar look with CSS, but can change the look of the scroll bar with a small JS plugin named Nicescroll. Here is the link you may found essential - https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post with a similar issue, and thought I'd mention that the difference between the two could be explained if you are using a mouse on your "other Mac", but not on the original machine.

But as stated [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218192/11343091), `overflow:auto;` would be a solution.